# how to load a dataframe from a python requests stream that is downloading a csv file?

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, python-requests

I would like to create a dataframe from a csv file that I will retrieve via streaming:

```
import requests

url = "https://{0}:8443/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/{1}?op=OPEN".format(host, filepath)

r = requests.get(url, 
                 auth=(username, password), 
                 verify=False, 
                 allow_redirects=True, 
                 stream=True)

chunk_size = 1024
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
    # how to load the data
```

How can the data be loaded into spark from the http stream?

Note that it isn't possible to use HDFS format for retrieving the data -  WebHDFS must be used.

Comment: You are looking to create a DataFrame while streaming the results you are receiving, correct ? You might want to look into Spark Streaming capabilities.

Comment: One the file has been imported the data is going to be analysed using core spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-generate the RDD of chunks' boundaries, then use it to process the file inside the worker. For examples:

```
def process(start, finish):
   // Download file
   // Process downloaded content in range [start, finish)
   // Return a list of item

partition_size = file_size / num_partition
boundaries = [(i, i+paritition_size - 1) for i in range(0, file_size, partition_size)]
rrd = sc.parallelize(boundaries).flatMap(process)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rrd)
```

Comment: Much nicer than my solution, which results in a stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187333/unionall-resulting-in-stackoverflow